# Как добавить в существующий скрипт функцию прокрутки страницы вверх?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, прокрутка

Добрый день! Этот скрипт автоматически прокручивает страницу к блоку .cover-b сразу после загрузки самой страницы.

```
<a href="#" id="top"><div class="arrow arrow_top"></div></a>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var height = $(this).height();
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop <= height) {
    $('html, body').delay(1).animate({
      scrollTop: $(".cover-b").offset().top
    }, 600, 'easeOutQuint', function() {
      if(!isComplete) {
         isComplete = true; 
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, добавить в существующий скрипт функцию прокрутки страницы вверх, при нажатии на ссылку с id="top". Благодарю за помощь!

html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="cover">
<div class="content">
</div>
<div class="cover-b"></div>
</div>

<div class="page" id="page">
</div>



<div id="top-panel">
<a href="#" id="top"><div class="arrow arrow_top"></div></a>
</div>

<div class="footer">
<div class="fbox">
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.cover {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: url(cover.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: right bottom;
    visibility: visible;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cover .content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.cover-b {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
}
.page {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
#top-panel {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 66px;
    top: 0;
}
#top {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    position: absolute;
}
#top .arrow {
    position: relative;
}
#top .arrow_top {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}
#top .arrow_top:after {
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

css вычистил от лишнего

Comment: @Jean-Claude, по приведенным ссылкам вопросы удалены

Comment: хтмл/цсс сюда...

Comment: http://jsbin.com/camopoqoze/edit?html,output

Comment: @LADYX ну так это был банальный пример, неужели я должен был  предугадать все ваши будущие пожелания и учесть их немедленно? :)

Answer (score 2):

На жиэсбине http://jsbin.com/camopoqoze/edit?html,output

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isComplete = false;
  var height = $(this).height();
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (scrollTop <= height) {
    $('html, body').delay(2).animate({
      scrollTop: $(".cover-c").offset().top
    }, 1500, function() {
      if (!isComplete) {
        isComplete = true;
      }
    });
  }

  $('a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($('.cover-a').height());
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(document).scrollTop() - $('.cover-a').height()
    }, 500)
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  height: 100%;
}
div.cover-a {
  background-color: #69f;
}
div.cover-b {
  background-color: tomato;
}
div.cover-c {
  background-color: green;
}
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 4px 3px 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>titile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="cover-a"></div>
  <div class="cover-b"></div>
  <div class="cover-c"></div>
  <a>Вверх</a>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var height = $(this).height();
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop <= height) {
    $('html, body').delay(1).animate({
      scrollTop: $(".cover-b").offset().top
    }, 600, 'easeOutQuint', function() {
    });
  }
});


$(function(){
  $.fn.scrollToTop=function(){
    $(this).hide().removeAttr("href");
    if($(window).scrollTop()!="0"){
        $(this).fadeIn("slow")
  }
  var scrollDiv=$(this);
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()=="0"){
    $(scrollDiv).fadeOut("slow")
    }else{
    $(scrollDiv).fadeIn("slow")
  }
  });
    $(this).click(function(){
      $("html, body, .pagebox").animate({scrollTop:0},"slow")
    })
  }
});
$(function() {$("#top").scrollToTop();});
```